# TS2339: Property 'tsReducer' does not exist on type 'DefaultRootState'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

Struggling with the above question. Seen similar questions but cannot figure it out.

The below code is me attempting to open and close a dialog using TypeScript for first time in an existing React project which uses .js and .jsx.

```
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Dialog from '@material-ui/core/Dialog';
import DialogActions from '@material-ui/core/DialogActions';
import DialogContent from '@material-ui/core/DialogContent';
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from 'react-redux';
import {closeTsDialog} from '../actions/tsDialog'
import {ActionTypes} from '../actions/types';

const TsApp = (): JSX.Element => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

// ERROR SHOWS UP ON LINE BELOW "state?.tsReducer?.isDialogOpen"
    const isDialogOpen = useSelector(state => state?.tsReducer?.isDialogOpen);
    const state = useSelector(s => s);
    console.log('->>>>>> state', state);


    // main tsx excluded to allow for posting on stackoverflow
};


export default TsApp;
```

```
import {TsDialogAction} from "../actions/tsDialog";


const initialState = {
    id: 0,
    isDialogOpen: false
};

const tsReducer = (state: TsDialogAction = initialState, action: Action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ActionTypes.closeDialog: {
            return {...state, isDialogOpen: false};
        }
        case ActionTypes.openDialog: {
            return {...state, isDialogOpen: true};
        }
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default tsReducer;
```

import {ActionTypes} from './types';

export interface TsDialogAction {
    isDialogOpen: boolean
    number: number
}

export interface CloseTsDialog {
    type: ActionTypes.closeDialog
    payload: TsDialogAction
}

export interface OpenTsDialog {
    type: ActionTypes.openDialog
    payload: TsDialogAction
}

export interface Increment {
    type: ActionTypes.increment
    payload: TsDialogAction
}

export interface Decrement {
    type: ActionTypes.decrement
    payload: TsDialogAction
}

export const closeTsDialog = (id: number) => ({type: ActionTypes.closeDialog, payload: id});
export const openTsDialog = (id: number) => ({type: ActionTypes.openDialog, payload: id});
export const incrementAction = (id: number) => ({type: ActionTypes.increment, payload: id});
export const decrementAction = (id: number) => ({type: ActionTypes.decrement, payload: id});

Answer (score 111):

It is complaining about the type. Quick solution would be adding `any` as state type.

Proper solution will require following two steps:

1. Create RootState type in Root Reducer.

```
export const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  dashboard: dashboardReducer,
  user: userReducer
});

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>
```

2. Provide RootState type to state object.

```
  let userData = useSelector((state: RootState) => {
    return state.user.data;
  });
```

Comment: This seems to be the best answer, thank you @Yuvraj

Answer (score 32):

You need to declare the type of the `state` argument in your selector, like:

```
const isDialogOpen = useSelector( (state: RootState) => state.tsReducer.isDialogOpen);
```

Please see the [Redux docs on TypeScript usage](https://redux.js.org/recipes/usage-with-typescript), as well as the [React-Redux docs page on static typing](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/static-typing) for examples.

(Also, as a stylistic note: please don't call that `tsReducer` in your root state.  Give it a name that matches the data it's handling, like `state.ui`.)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer the question. However, I am still seeing the same error.

Comment: Can you update the question with the actual type declaration code you're trying to use?

Comment: updated question as requested but wasn't allow to put it in ```code```

Answer (score 32):

If you are using react-redux, another out of the box solution would be to use `RootStateOrAny`.

```
import { RootStateOrAny, useSelector } from 'react-redux';

// and then use it like so in your component
...
const authState = useSelector((state: RootStateOrAny) => state.auth);
...
```

Comment: this answer was the simplest

Answer (score 29):

For me, a better solution than specifying state in useSelector would be as below.
As in the `node_modules/@types/react-redux/index.d.ts`, you can use module augmentation.

```
/**
 * This interface can be augmented by users to add default types for the root state when
 * using `react-redux`.
 * Use module augmentation to append your own type definition in a your_custom_type.d.ts file.
 * https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation
 */
// tslint:disable-next-line:no-empty-interface
export interface DefaultRootState {}
```

Do as below

1. Export AppState in reducer `src/reducer/index.ts`

```js
const reducers = combineReducers({
  userReducer,
});

export type AppState = ReturnType<typeof reducers>;
```

2. Create new `your_custom_type.d.ts`. (I prefer react-redux.d.ts).
   In `src/@types/your_custom_type.d.ts`

```js
import 'react-redux';

import { AppState } from '../reducers';

declare module 'react-redux' {
  interface DefaultRootState extends AppState { };
}
```

3. Add `typeRoots` in tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "typeRoots": ["src/@types"]
  }
}
```

**You can use as below without specifying AppState**

```js
import React, { memo } from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

export default memo(() => {
  const isLoggedIn = useSelector(
    ({ userReducer }) => userReducer.isLoggedIn
  );
  return <div>{isLoggedIn}</div>;
});
```

Comment: Elegant solution !

Comment: Great answer and this solution is tidy and it works.

Comment: Fantastic solution. Thanks for sharing... way cleaner than importing AppState on every usage. 

Comment: Great solution. Actually, this could work with any other libraries too. Brilliant

Answer (score 7):

These are useful articles.

1. https://redux.js.org/recipes/usage-with-typescript#define-root-state-and-dispatch-types
2. https://redux.js.org/recipes/usage-with-typescript#define-typed-hooks

So first define `RootState` and `AppDispatch` like following:

```
//at store/index.ts
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  tsReducer: tsReducer
});
const store = createStore(rootReducer)

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch
```

And then define hooks (`useAppDispatch`, `useAppSelector`) can be used in components.

```
//at store/hooks.ts
import { TypedUseSelectorHook, useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import type { RootState, AppDispatch } from './'

export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>()
export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector
```

And use it on component like following:

```
import {useAppSelector} from '../store/hooks'
//...
const TsApp = (): JSX.Element => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

// ERROR should be fixed
    const isDialogOpen = useAppSelector(state => state.tsReducer.isDialogOpen);
};
```

Answer (score 6):

this worked for me

```
import { RootStateOrAny, useSelector } from "react-redux"

const search = useSelector((state: RootStateOrAny) => state.searchObj.values)
```

in non-react components just functions or hooks you can do

```
import {store} from "../redux/store"

const search: SearchProps | any = store.getState().searchObj.values
```

Answer (score 0):

it is just about types that you need to satisfy to this hook, `useSelector` accepts `DefaultRootState` type, you can override its default types through this

```js
type User = {
  firstname: string;
  lastname: string;
};
type SelectorTypes = {
  users: User[];
  //...other reducers
};
const router = useSelector<SelectorTypes>((state) => state.users);
```